# Explain the jvm memory structure?

Tags: memory, architecture, jvm, structure, allocation

Can anyone please explain the structure of JVM memory or I should say runtime data areas in JVM.

Answer (score 1):

Eden, new gen, old gen, perm space - objects are migrated from one to the other depending on how many gc cycles they survive.

You can read about it [here](http://java.sun.com/j2se/reference/.../memorymanagement_whitepaper.pdf).

Comment: LInk to see the pdf file is is not working [memorymanagement_whitepaper](http://java.sun.com/j2se/reference/.../memorymanagement_whitepaper.pdf)

Comment: Here is the link which seems to be working [here](http://java.sun.com/j2se/reference/whitepapers/memorymanagement_whitepaper.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

You can read about the JVM memory structure [here](http://java-espresso.blogspot.com/2011/04/memory-structure-in-jvm.html).

Comment: You can read about heap memory in very detail and the same time very precise article at [here](http://java-espresso.blogspot.com/2011/05/heap-structure-in-jvm.html)